# Link to https://suite.office.net/data.theme?action... fails

Tags: sharepoint-online, theme

all. My client site is using a link to

https://suite.office.net/data.theme?action=tcspo&v=1&tc=%23339933%7C%23444444%7C%23339933%7C%23ffffff%7C%2392c0e0%7Crgba(239%2C%20239%2C%20239%2C%200.80)%7C%23333333%7C%23333333%7C%23ffffff%7Crgba(203%2C%20237%2C%20203%2C%200.50)%7C%23e5e5e5&l=en-US

as part of the site request. This call fails every time with net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I see on other site people have https://office.portal.com/data.theme?action=tcspo&v=1&tc=%23339933%7C%23444444%7C%23339933%7C%23ffffff%7C%2392c0e0%7Crgba(239%2C%20239%2C%20239%2C%200.80)%7C%23333333%7C%23333333%7C%23ffffff%7Crgba(203%2C%20237%2C%20203%2C%200.50)%7C%23e5e5e5&l=en-US, and this works. When I replace the former with the latter, it works for me too.

My question is: Where is this value set? I know it is rendered as such:

I also know it is assigned to a key (somewhere) called LoadUserThemesUrl.

I need to change my URL so that I don't have this 21 second blocking call, initiated from a MSFT script that I cannot change. I simply cannot find out where this sort of change would be. It didn't appear to be part of the theme change page in O365 settings.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Sean

Comment: This site uses Markdown to format things. Please click [edit] (under your question, or on the word right there) and look at the right sidebar; there's a brief formatting guide. Follow it.